# Is there any Zend Session handler library for MongoDB?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, mongodb

Is there a good Session handler MongoDb library for Zend ?
Am using Zend 1.12.
I know that Zend 2.0 has its own implementation of Zend_Session_SaveHandler for Mongo. But there's no plan to upgrade anytime soon.
Appreciate all the inputs/advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a MongoDb session handler on [this page](http://gertonscorner.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/zend-framework-mongodb-session-savehandler/).
The source code can be downloaded from [here](http://gertonscorner.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/phplib/GcLib/Zend/Session/SaveHandler/MongoDb.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had checked this earlier before posting the question but i was a little hesitant since i din't see anyone using it or commenting on it. Is it something that you have tried ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not tried it, since I'm not using MongoDb